# Returning any derived class type from a method outside the base and derived class

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I have three classes: `BaseInfo`, `CarInfo`, and `PetInfo`. The `BaseInfo` class is the base class. `CarInfo` inherits from `BaseInfo`, and has properties related to a car. Finally, `PetInfo` also inherits from `BaseInfo`, and has properties related to a pet:

```
public class BaseInfo
{
  [JsonIgnore]
  public int UserId { get; set; }
  [JsonIgnore]
  public string UserName { get; set; }
  [JsonIgnore]
  public DateTime RegistrationDate { get; set; } 
  [JsonIgnore]
  public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }    
}

public class CarInfo : BaseInfo
{
  [JsonPropertyName("car_make")] 
  public string Make { get; set; }
  [JsonPropertyName("car_model")]
  public string Model { get; set; }  
  …
}

public class PetInfo : BaseInfo
{
  [JsonPropertyName("pet_breed")] 
  public string Breed { get; set; }
  [JsonPropertyName("pet_weight")]
  public long Weight { get; set; } 
  …
}
```

Then I have a service whose purpose is to retrieve data and, in the case of the method in question, to create a list of either cars or pets for a particular user:

```
public class SomeService : ISomeService
{
  public List<ANY_OF_THE_DERIVED_CLASSES> GetInfoList(string type, int userId)
  {
    List<ANY_OF_THE_DERIVED_CLASSES> infoList = new List<ANY_OF_THE_DERIVED_CLASSES>;
    switch (type)
    {
      case "car":
        infoList = GetCarList(userId);
        break;
      case "pet":
        infoList = GetPetList(userId);
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
    return infoList;
  }

  private List<CarInfo> GetCarList(int userId)
  {
    var carList = new List<CarInfo>();

    //Logic that receives manipulates and serializes data against CarInfo and adds to list

    return carList;
  }

  private List<PetInfo> GetPetList(int userId)
  {
    var petList = new List<PetInfo>();

    //Logic that receives manipulates and serializes data against PetInfo and adds to list

    return petList;
  }
}
```

I've also created an interface for `SomeService`, which is defined as:

```
 public interface ISomeService
 {
   List<ANY_OF_THE_DERIVED_CLASSES> GetInfoList(string type, int userId)
 }
```

Is it possible to get the `GetInfoList` method to have the ability to return either `List<CarInfo>` or `List<PetInfo>`?

Comment: You probably just want a generic method `List<T> GetInfoList<T>(...)`

Comment: `List<T> GetInfoList<T>(string type, int userId) where T: BaseInfo` would be the correct generic signature

Comment: And adding to @CamiloTerevinto reply,  the list will be able to hold any of those types as long as they are BaseInfo (i.e. the list can hold both PetInfo and CarInfo at same time).

Comment: After changing the method to the suggested `public List<T> GetInfoList(string type, int userId) where T : BaseInfo` The following errors occur: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<CarInfo>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<T>'` and `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<PetInfo>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<T>'`

Comment: @so_as: The missing piece here is likely that you need to provide a conversion from e.g. `List<CarInfo>` to `List<T>`. You might well expect this would be implicit, but it's not. In addition, you don't need to pass in `string type`; you can get that via e.g. `nameof(T)`. I've expanded on Camilo's guidance in a full answer below, along with a unit test to validate the functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The guidance by @Camilo-Terevinto in the comments is exactly right, but might leave you with some additional questions if you're new to generics. To provide a more comprehensive example, here's what your code—as you proposed it—should look like:

#### `ISomeService`

```cs
public interface ISomeService 
{
    List<T> GetInfoList<T>(int userId) where T : BaseInfo;
}
```

#### `SomeService`

```cs
public class SomeService: ISomeService 
{
    public List<T> GetInfoList<T>(int userId) where T : BaseInfo 
    {
        List<T> infoList;
        switch (nameof(T)) 
        {
            case nameof(CarInfo):
                infoList = GetCarList(userId) as List<T>;
                break;
            case nameof(PetInfo):
                infoList = GetPetList(userId) as List<T>;
                break;
            default:
                infoList = new List<T>();
                break;
        }
        return infoList;
    }
    …
}
```

#### Validation

You can validate that this works using e.g. the following test class:

```cs
[TestClass]
public class SomeServiceTests 
{

    [TestMethod]
    public void GetInfoList_ShouldReturn_ListCarInfo() 
    {

      var service   = new SomeService();
      var list      = service.GetInfoList<CarInfo>(1);

      list.Add(new CarInfo());

      Assert.IsNotNull(list);
      Assert.AreEqual<int>(1, list.Count);

    }
```

#### Notes

- You need to convert the e.g. `List<CarInfo>` to `List<T>` when defining `infoList`.
- You don't need to pass in the `type` as a parameter, as you can determine that based on the `T` type parameter (via e.g. `nameof(T)`).
- You don't need to initialize `infoList` upfront since, in most cases, it will be immediately replaced with the results of e.g. `GetCarList()`.
- If this is a publicly available interface as part of a reusable library, you should prefer returning `Collection<T>` over `List<T>` ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/guidelines-for-collections)).
- From a design perspective, I don't love having the hard-coded switch statement with a 1:1 relationship to initialization methods, but without further insight into your business requirements I'm leaving those as is.

#### Further Optimizations

This is aside from your original question, but with C# 8.0's pattern matching, you can clean up your switch statement a bit to simply:

```cs
public List<T> GetInfoList<T>(int userId) where T : BaseInfo => 
    nameof(T) switch 
    {
        nameof(CarInfo) => GetCarList(userId) as List<T>,
        nameof(PetInfo) => GetPetList(userId) as List<T>,
        _ => new List<T>()
    };
```

Comment: But... But... What if someone derives another class called `CarInfo` in a different namespace? If there's only two choices I'd stick with if/else checking typeof... At least until [this is implemented](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/356)

Comment: @pinkfloydx33: Yes, certainly an important caveat to be aware of! Also, thank you for making me aware of that proposal; that's something I've long wanted, and especially for handling dependency injection without a container.